# Monty Hall and Lazy Sequences (?)

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, statistics

I'm just starting to learn Clojure and I'm trying to simulate the [Monty Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) problem:

```
(defn create-contest
  "Creates a monty hall doors contest"
  [n]
  (do (def door-with-car (rand-int n))
      (map
       (fn [i] (if (= i door-with-car) :car :closed))
       (range n)))) 

(defn create-doors
  "Create a collection of monty hall contests"
  [doors contests]
  (doall
   (map
     (fn [i] (create-contest i))
     (repeat contests doors))))
```

But every time I execute the `create-doors` function all the doors with cars end up in the same position:

```
broker.core> (create-doors 4 10)
((:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed)
 (:car :closed :closed :closed))
broker.core> (create-doors 4 10)
((:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed))
broker.core> (create-doors 4 10)
((:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close, you should just use a `let` form instead of `def` here:

```
(defn create-contest
  "Creates a monty hall doors contest"
  [n]
  (let [door-with-car (rand-int n)] ;; let instead of def
    (map
      (fn [i] (if (= i door-with-car) :car :closed))
      (range n))))
```

`def` will bind some value to a var in the current namespace, but you want to bind a value in the scope of this function, and that's what `let` is good for. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897707/clojure-defining-a-variable-inside-of-a-function/48897850#48897850) for another explanation.

```
(defn create-doors
  "Create a collection of monty hall contests"
  [doors contests]
  (map
    create-contest ;; no need to wrap create-contest in another function here
    (repeat contests doors)))
```

You don't need to wrap `create-contest` in another function for use with `map` — you can just pass the function directly to `map` as a value. The `doall` is only necessary to force realization of the lazy sequence from `map`, so you probably don't need/want that inside `create-doors`.

```
(create-doors 4 10)
=>
((:closed :closed :car :closed)
 (:closed :closed :closed :car)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :closed :closed :car)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :car :closed :closed)
 (:closed :closed :closed :car)
 (:closed :closed :car :closed)
 (:closed :closed :car :closed))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [@TaylorWood's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975163/1562315), you can express both your functions more concisely, though I'm not sure the concise versions are as clear.

Your `create-contest`'s `map`'s function tests every number `i` to see if it is *the one*. Better just change *the one* directly. To do that, we need a vector, which I think you'll want to look up anyway when simulating the game:

```
 (defn create-contest [n]
  (assoc (vec (repeat n :closed)) (rand-int n) :car))
```

Your `create-doors` function repeatedly passes the same argument to its `map`'s function. You can use [`repeatedly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly) on a closure to get the same effect:

```
(defn create-doors [doors contests]
  (repeatedly contests (partial create-contest doors)))
```

Or

```
(defn create-doors [doors contests]
  (repeatedly contests #(create-contest doors)))
```