# How can you create a large nested vector without explicitely writing down the values?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a nested vector [[1 randint1] [2 randint2] ...] up until 100 without looping, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

I've tried creating a multiple hash-maps, but once they're stored in a vector I can't convert the inner maps to vectors as well.

```clj
(def rands (take 100 (repeatedly #(rand-int 100))))
(println (vec(map #(hash-map %1 %2) (range 100) rands)))
```

expect [[1 randint1] [2 randint2] ...] but get [{1 randint1} {2 randint2} ...]

Here's a loop variant that produces the correct output

```clj
(def foo {})

  (loop
    [i 1]    
    (when (< i 100)
      (def foo (conj foo [i (rand-int 100)]))
      (recur (inc i))))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `[[1 randint1] [2 randint2] ...]` isn't a nested map, it's a nested vector. Is that what you want? Also, don't use `def` like you're using it there. Add `foo` under `i` in `loop`'s accumulator list. This looks like a job for `reduce` or even `map` though.

Comment: something like `(for [i (range 100)]
 [(inc i) (rand-int 100)])` ?

Comment: Apologies, it is a nested vector I want.

Comment: @JoachimSmith Yes, so just use what akond suggested, or something like `(mapv (fn [i] [(inc i) (rand-int 100)]) (range 100))` which is essentially equivalent to theirs.

Comment: And see [Taylor's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897850/3000206) that talks about use of `def`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akond for the help. This works:

```clj
(vec (for [i (range 100)] [(inc i) (rand-int 100)])))
```