# Read a file containing data and print values 10 characters before and after into a new file if string "john" is found

Tags: clojure

I need to print 10 characters before and after string "john",whenever "john" is encountered. Even though half of letters are printed in the next line,it should still print 10 characters before and after.

I have tried using .contains function and using the index of string but the problem arises when i input a file like this:

```
Hello my name is jo
hn and i work for bla bla.
```

What I tried:

```
(ns clojure-assignment.problem6
  (:use [clojure.string :only [index-of]]))

(defn String_manipulation []
  (def str1 (slurp "string.txt"))
  (println str1)
  (def check (.contains str1 "john"))
  (if (= check true)
    (def index (index-of str1 "john")))    
  (println (subs str1 (- index 11) index))
  (println (subs str1 (+ index 4) (+ index  5 10))))

(String_manipulation)
```

I expect the output to print values 10 characters before and after the given string and it should also work if there is a line end.

Comment: `clojure-assignment.problem6` makes this look a lot like homework. Also you should use `let` instead of `def` inside the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897850

Comment: Try regular expressions. They are so much fun.

Comment: @TaylorWood homework isn't necessarily bad if it meets all the other site requirements. Unless you are yourself the teacher in question, in which case, fire away.

Comment: @akond regex doesn't seem to be trivial, like in case of `1234567890johnjohn1234567890` . well, unless you just meant to use `#"john"`, but in this case it is like `indexOf`

Comment: @leetwinski OP seems to want it to match "Jo hn" as well. At this point I think it's just unclear.

Comment: It's not clear from reading the instructions that "jo\nhn" should match this. sure looks like a different string.

Comment: well as per my logic we can treat the whole file as one string,and we can read the file line by line,i am not sure though if that could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```clj
(def s "Hello my name is jo
hn and i work for bla bla.
")

(re-seq #".{10}john.{10}" (str/replace s #"\n" ""))
;; => ("y name is john and i wor")
```

*UPDATE 1 - overlapping pattern*

If pattern is expected to be overlapping, use look ahead regex and extract from the matched group:

```clj
(def s "hello my name is john-john and john is my father's name")

(re-seq #"(?=(.{10}john.{10}))" (str/replace s #"\n" ""))

(["" "y name is john-john and "]
 ["" "e is john-john and john "]
 ["" "-john and john is my fat"])
```

*UPDATE 2 - print prefix and suffix match group*

```clj
(use 'clojure.pprint)

(def s "Hello my name is jo
hn and i work for bla bla.
")

(->> (str/replace s #"\n" "")
     (re-seq #"(?=(.{10})john(.{10}))")
     (cl-format *out* "~{~{~a~}~%~}"))
;; => y name is  and i wor
```

Comment: what about "john did"?

Comment: it is a nice and simple logic but if u could change it a little bit,

Comment: @rmcv the output should not display john at all

Comment: @akond - "john did" can be done with padding - if you don't want to further complicate the regex.

Comment: @CoDInGbrO - the output should not display john at all - can be done by cutting the matched john out; or use two match groups.